# Como realizar un Bulk Copy de SQL desde una carpeta compartida?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como realizar un Bulk Copy de SQL desde una carpeta compartida?? Tengo implementado el siguiente codigo pero no funciona.

Code:

```
FROM '\\CFLTIPRGMS04PC\Users\lbzepeda\Desktop\Pruebas H2H\BLNI\AJENICARAGUA\AJENIC2020021411_L001 - Copy.csv'
WITH
( FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
  ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
);
```

Resultado:

```
Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 24
Cannot bulk load because the file "\\CFLTIPRGMS04PC\Users\lbzepeda\Desktop\Pruebas H2H\BLNI\AJENICARAGUA\AJENIC2020021411_L001 - Copy.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.).
```

les ha pasado esto alguna vez?

Comment: (Access is denied.) El problema es los permisos de ese usuario a la carpeta. Estás utilizando SQL con autenticación de windows? mixta? el usuario SQL está en las directivas de la carpeta?

Comment: El archivo está abierto y siendo bloqueado por otro programa?